# How i can be sure that JMeter is not using the same sample more than one time at same time?

Tags: jmeter

I'm using JMeter to test my applications, and I desire to use the same sample N times.

For example, lets say I have 100 different samples how I'll use to test my Login, and want to use these samples 10 times.

I'm using 100 threads, and 10 loops for that.

How I can be sure that the second loop using a sample will start just after that the first loop of that sample has finished (and not have the same sample running simultanious)?

I'm having some troubles to understand how JMeter lead to this scenario.

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-count-retries-as-a-single-request-in-jmeter/ this might help you

Answer (score 0):

JMeter acts as follows:

1. Each thread (virtual users) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
2. When there are no more Samplers to execute:

   -if there is > 1 loop in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - the thread starts executing Samplers once again

   - if there are no more loops to iterate - the thread is being shut down

You can track which thread is executing which sampler by adding [__threadNum()](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) function to the sampler name. The Thread Group iteration can be tracked by adding the special [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}`

[image]

If you don't want user 1 and user 2 to execute sampler1 at the same time - put this sampler under the [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller), but in this case you will not have any concurrency.

Comment: Hello Dmitri, thanks for your anwser. My scenario is different of what you use as example (user 1 and user 2 to execute sampler1 at the same time), I want to be sure that sampler 1 is not being used for more than one thread and loop at same time. I think the option of Critical Section Controller can be the awnser to me, do you agree?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you need all the users to execute the sampler at exactly the same moment - add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) as a child of this sampler and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to the desired number of the concurrent requests (must be equal or less to the number of threads in the Thread Group)

Comment: Thanks for this option, I'll consider in the future tests, but at the moment I just want to be sure that sampler 1 is not being used for more than one thread and loop at same time (
(because we have rules that monitor calls). The same sampler will be use N times in the test scenario, I think the option of Critical Section Controller will be enougth to ensure that, right? Thanks man, help me a lot =D